# Alert Creation for All VMs under same subscription in Azure using Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring

```
**I am trying to deploy below terraform alert for all VMs under my subscription, and subscription id I've kept it in variables file. But its throwing below error.
```

Also how can I define type as MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria for this below template as in ARM templates we can define this type as odata.type but when I try odata_type in terraform its not accepting it.
also is there any way I can grab subscription id at runtime using query instead of passing subscription id in variables file. Is there any quickstart template site for the terraform for reference.

```
Error: **Can not parse "scopes.0" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "{subscription_id is getting printed here}":** invalid URI for request**

  on metric.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example":
   1: resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
```

terraform.tf file

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = "MyTemp"
  scopes              = ["${var.subscription_id}"]
  description         = "Action will be triggered when Transactions count is greater than 50."
  target_resource_type = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
  
  criteria { 
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    metric_name      = "Percentage CPU"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 50
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups/xxxxx"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Data Source: azurerm_subscription](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subscription.html) to access information about an existing Subscription.

terraform.tf file will look like this:

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {

  subscription_id  = var.subscription_id
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = "MyTemp"
  scopes              = [data.azurerm_subscription.current.id]
  description         = "Action will be triggered when Transactions count is greater than 50."
  target_resource_type = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
  
  criteria { 
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    metric_name      = "Percentage CPU"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 50
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups/xxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for first time I deployed and then I deleted the alerts and trying to deploy now error is .. Message="targetResourceRegion property is missing or invalid

Comment: Could you describe what's specific steps are you doing? Did you delete the alerts in terraform destroy or on the Azure portal? When you re-run your terraform, you could clear the .tfstate file.

Comment: I deleted alerts in azure portal

Comment: You can add the `target_resource_location= "eastus"`, (example) because This is Required when using a Subscription as scope, a Resource Group as scope or Multiple Scopes. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_metric_alert.html#target_resource_location

Comment: Hi Nancy, One more thing the same template I am trying to use for Guest Metrics but I am getting below error, I have changed namespace to Azure.VM.Windows.GuestMetrics and trying to deploy metric name - Memory\% Committed bytes in use
 Message="Multi-resource alert rules are not supported for metrics in the Azure.VM.Windows.GuestMetrics namespace

Comment: As the error displayed, "Multi-resource alert rules are not supported for metrics in the Azure.VM.Windows.GuestMetrics namespace" I guess you can not create multiple alerts with such metric namespace in subscription scopes. So, in logic, if you want to create VMs in a subscription, I think it's better to create individual `resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert"` with individual VM id as the scope, then reference your existing VMs in a loop. I have not validated it but you can have a try.

Comment: I have created new question thread for this issue , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168103/unable-to-deploy-guest-metrics-using-terraform-in-azure
Let's have discussion over there.